# Access express app level variables in custom routes javascript file

Tags: node.js, express

In the app.js file, I have declared a app.locals property, say :

```
app.locals.targetUrl = 'hello world!!'
```

How can I access this property from custom javascript file. I have a custom js file containing routes and I need to refer the targetUrl property in the routes.js file.

> Scenario

Say I have a restful api hosted at : http://localhost:55555/visit. Now In my routes file, I am appending depending upon the route, additional route suffixes e.g http://localhost:55555/visit/all or http://localhost:55555/visit/weekend etc. What I am looking for is a way to declare the base Url http://localhost:55555/visit once in app.js file and then be able to refer this as property in other routes file.

Comment: Not sure I get it, generally you use `app.locals` to pass things to the HTML templates in middleware such as Jade, EJS etc ?

Comment: I have modified the question by adding additional information. I am able to access the app.locals property in template files. Its just that I want to declare a property once in app.js and then reuse it in all routes files.

Comment: You could always do `global.targetUrl = 'something'` and attach it to the global object, but it's probably better to pass it to the routes as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `express.Router`? You can just set the path for the entire router in your app.js file.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes');

app.use('/visit', routes); // Set here

app.listen(3000);
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = module.exports = express.Router();

// GET /visit
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

});

// GET /visit/weekend
app.get('/weekend', function(req, res) {

});
```